# Modify textbox from child class in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, textbox, parent-child

I have windows form application with textbox and public function which set text to this textbox as follows

```
public void set_textbox(string msg)
{
    Console.WriteLine("?1");
    textbox.Text = "asd";
    Console.WriteLine("?2");
}
```

I need to update this textbox from another class (this second class is maintained by Quartz scheduler which creates its instances and do stuff itself, so I do not create it instances on my own). In order to achieve this, second class is inherited from the first one, so I have access to the `set_textbox` method.

```
public class myjob : Form1, IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        set_textbox("test");                
    }
}
```

Problem is that although function `set_textbox` is called properly (I can see both control messages - "?1" and "?2", there is no text in the textbox at all.

I also tried to call this function from first class which defines textbox and it does work - it does not from the child class (control messages yes, textbox modification no)

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: You do not assign the method argument 'msg' to the textbox.

Comment: Yes,this is just testcase, I do not even get "asd" in textbox

Comment: Okay, you execute the job on the myjob instance, that is created dynamically. The visible Form1 instance cannot display the job text, because that are different objects. You should somehow configure Quartz to transfer the Form1 instance reference to your job.

Comment: you'll wanna use an event so you don't have bidirectional dependency - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51236680/invoke-button-from-another-form-in-c-sharp/51236912#51236912

Comment: I will try. Thanks a lot guys!